# The maximal unramified extension of a local field may not be complete

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

While reading my notes of a course in local class field theory, I arrived to a remark where it is said that given a complete discrete valuation field $K$, its maximal unramified extension
$$K^{ur}= \bigcup_{F / K \: fin. unr.} F $$
may not be complete. I was going to ask for a concrete example (that is, a Cauchy sequence in $K^{ur}$ that doesn't converge), but after some research in google I found one as an exercise in *Local Fields and Their Extensions*, by Ivan B. Fesenko, S. V. Vostokov:

> Let $\pi \in K$ be a prime element, and let $k^{sep}$ be of infinite degree over $k$ (as in $K = \Bbb Q_p$, $k = \Bbb F_p$). Let $K_i$ be finite unramified extension of $K$, with $K_i$ strictly contained in $K_j$ for $i < j$. (We can do this in the above example because we have a 1.1 correspondence between finite unramified extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$ and finite extensions of $\Bbb F_p$.) Define
> $$ \alpha_n := \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i \pi^i $$
> where $ \theta_i \in \mathcal{O}_{K_{i+1}} \setminus \mathcal{O}_{K_i}$. Show that $(\alpha_i)$ is a Cauchy sequence and that $\lim_n \alpha_n$ is not in $K^{ur}$.

Well, to show that it is a Cauchy sequence is trivial, and to see that the limit is not in $K^{ur}$ we argue like this: if it is in the union, it belongs to one of the $K_i$'s, but this contradicts the fact that $\alpha_j \notin K_j$ for $j > i$. **Edit:** The contradiction only appears once we fix representatives of $\mathcal{O}_{\widehat{K^{ur}}}$, see the nice counterexample by Torsten Schoeneberg below for details.

So here my question comes: how does the closure of $K^{ur}$ look like? [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85204/ring-of-witt-vectors-and-p-adics) an answer is given for $K = \Bbb Q_p$, but they just mention what it is and an explanation of this or an answer to my more general question will be welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'look like'? That explanation works well for $\mathbb{Q}_{p^r}$ as well. What do you want in general? Also, it's worth mentioning, if $K$ is local, and $L/K$ an extension. Then, $L$ is complete if and only if $L$ is a finite extension. This follows pretty easily from the Baire category theorem.

Comment: I'm asking for the completion of $K^{ur}$ wrt the absolute value induced by the one in $K$. You can always take the completion, and since $K^{ur}$ is not complete, we will get something different. What? This is what I'm asking. For general I want to start with a different complete discrete valuation field (for example of positive characteristic). And I don't understand how can you use he Baire category theorem to conclude that, could you expand it to an answer? Thank you!

Comment: I can write up an answer, but it won't be more satisfactory than Lubin's answer below (which, as I commented, is the same as the answer in the post you linked). As for the Baire category theorem, proceed as follows. Let $L/K$ be infinite, and for each finite subextension $F$, let $U_F$ be $L-F$. Show that each $U_F$ is dense, and open, but $\displaystyle \bigcap U_F=\varnothing$. But, if $L$ were complete, it would be a Baire space, but the above shows this is not true.

Comment: @PedroA.Castillejo can you explain  why does the limit doesn't exist in the argument you have given, i get the fact that $\alpha_j \not \in  F_I$ for all $ j >i$, but why does that imply the limit is not in $\alpha_i$. Also in the above comment how we show that $F$ is closed in L?

Comment: @PedroA.Castillejo can you explain why if $\alpha_j \not \in F_i$ for all $ j >i$ implies that the limit is not in $F_i$?

Comment: The idea is the following: each $\alpha_i \in K_i \setminus K_{i-1}$, so when you make $i$ go to infinity, it will not be in any $K_i$. The limit exists, but it is not in any finite extension. Is this clearer?

Comment: So where we are exactly using the unramified condition?

Comment: @ChirantanChowdhury I was interested in the maximal unramified extension itself, I'm not using the unramified condition itself. What I use is that $K^{ur} = \bigcup K_i$

Comment: Ok i figured out this proof using baire category theorem . Showing the finite extension is closed is easy by completeness but showing the complement is dense needs a bit of work.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927760/

Comment: @ChirantanChowdhury (comment from Jun 17, 2017): Very good catch! It does indeed *not* imply that in this generality. See my answer for a counterexample. (I somehow felt the arguments were too handwavy myself, but only after seeing your comments did I sit down to isolate the flaw and found the counterexample (easy in hindsight, but needed the motivation).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a natural question, because it’s really easy to get overwhelmed by the situation. In the case of the completion of the maximal unramified of a local field $k$, here’s the way that I look at things: you have the maximal unramified extension, which I’ll call $K$, an infinite algebraic extension gotten by adjoining the $(p^n-1)$-th roots of unity for all $n$. Let’s call $\mathcal O$ the integers of $K$.

Now for the completion, $\overline K$: you can think of the elements of the integers there as series $\sum_ia_i\pi^i$, where each $a_i$ is in $\mathcal O$ and where $\pi$ is a chosen prime element of $k$. This representation isn’t unique. If you want a unique representation, restrict the $a_i$ all to be roots of unity of the type I mentioned above, or zero (these are the “Teichmüller representatives”).

If you start thinking about the completion of the *algebraic closure* of $k$, things get *really* confusing, partly because there’s no unique representation of an element there. But the first description in the paragraph above works in that case just as well.

Comment: Dear Lubin, I believe you're rewriting what was linked in the original post. That if $k$ is the residue field of $K$, the $\widehat{K^\mathrm{u.r.}}$ is $W(\overline{k})$. I agree that this is a reasonable description, but perhaps this is not what the OP is looking for. But, perhaps I am confused.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, you may be right. But I can not imagine a more perspicuous description.

Comment: And of course, @AlexYoucis, if the base was a ramified field, then the maximal unramified is no longer described by the Witt construction.

Comment: That's a good point. But, it seems that in your description, you are exactly describing $W(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})$. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @AlexYoucis, because I took powers of $\pi$, not powers of $p$. Naturally (because $k$ is finite over $\Bbb Q_p$), what I described is the tensor product of $k$ with (the fraction field of) the Witt vectors, but it certainly is not the Witt-construction *tout simple*.

Answer (score 3):

**TL, DR**: One claim cited in the question is actually wrong in the generality it is stated there, and some short arguments given for it are flawed; however, the issue can be fixed in sufficient special cases if one invokes more structure theory (as alluded to in Lubin's answer, which is, of course, entirely correct).

---

**1.** The exercise quoted in the OP is exercise 1a to chapter II, section 3 in Fesenko/Vostokov, [page 55 here](https://ivanfesenko.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/vol.pdf) (they use $F$ where we use $K$). But part of what is claimed there, namely, that

> for $ \alpha_n := \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i \pi^i$ (where $ \theta_i \in \mathcal{O}_{K_{i+1}} \setminus \mathcal{O}_{K_i}$), we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n \notin K^{ur}$

is actually **wrong** unless one is more restrictive about what $\theta_i$ are allowed.

**Example**. Since $17$ is my favourite number, I will show an example where $\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n = 17 p$ which quite obviously is $\in K^{ur}$.

Indeed, let $K = \mathbb Q_p, \pi =p$, $K_i := \mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{p^i-1})$, and let

$$\theta_1 := 17 - p \zeta_{p^2-1}$$

and for $i \ge 2$,

$$\theta_i := \zeta_{p^{i}-1} - p \zeta_{p^{i+1}-1}.$$

Then $\theta_i \in \mathcal{O}_{K_{i+1}} \setminus \mathcal{O}_{K_i}$ but we also have $$\alpha_n = 17p - p^{n+1} \zeta_{p^{n+1}-1}$$ for all $n$, so as claimed $\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n = 17p \in \mathbb Z \subset K^{ur}$.

---

**2.** The issue with supposed arguments showing that the limit is $\notin K^{ur}$, like in the OP

> if it is in the union, it belongs to one of the $K_i$'s, but this contradicts the fact that $\alpha_j \notin K_j$ [maybe $K_i$ is meant here, but it does not matter] for $j > i$.

is that while the first implication (that it belongs to some $K_i$) is true, and while it is also true that $\alpha_j \notin K_i$ for any $j \ge i$ (this holds true in my example in **1** too), these things just do not contradict each other. In a comment it is written

> each $\alpha_i \in K_i \setminus K_{i-1}$, so when you make $i$ go to infinity, it will not be in any $K_i$. The limit exists, but it is not in any finite extension.

but these vague words contain an **invalid conclusion from the terms of a sequence to its limit**; as the example shows, we can very well have a sequence whose *individual terms* leave any finite extension, but that tells us more or less nothing about *its limit*.

I admit at first those claims sounded plausible to me too, but I also assume once one sees what the issue is, one sees how I made up my example, and how one can easily make many more.

---

**3.** How we can save what we want:

Of course e.g. Lubin is well aware of these things, but politely hides them a little in his answer, in the short remarks about uniqueness of certain representations. This idea does provide us with examples where the argument goes through. One just has to put a little more work into this, as in

**Example**: If in the situation described in 1 we instead let $$\theta_i := \zeta_{p^{i+1}-1},$$ then indeed $\lim \alpha_n \notin K^{ur}$.

Namely, the *completion* $\widehat{K^{ur}}$ is a field with a discrete valuation, uniformizer $p$, residue field $\mathbb F_p^{alg}$, and (by definition) complete. Hence, by general structure theory for such fields, *once we fix a set of representatives* $R \subset \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{K^{ur}}}$ of the residue field, then the standard series representation with such representatives is unique, i.e. if $\sum \beta_n p^n = \sum \gamma_n p^n$ and all $\beta_i, \gamma_i \in R$, then for all $n$ we have $\beta_n =\gamma_n$. But the joke is that we can choose a set of such representatives which is compatible with our tower of fields $K_i$; for example, letting $R_i := \mu_{p^i-1}$ (all roots of unity of order $p^i-1$) and $R:= \bigcup R_i$, now we can put the supposed arguments in **2** on solid ground: Namely, if $\alpha:=\lim \alpha_n \in K^{ur} = \bigcup K_i$, then it is in some $K_i$; but *because $R_{i}$ is also a set of representatives of the residue field of the complete field $K_i$*, this means there is *also* a representation

$$\alpha = \sum \gamma_n \cdot p^n \qquad \qquad (I)$$

with *all $\gamma_n \in R_i$*. But in $\widehat K^{ur}$, of course we still have

$$\alpha = \sum \zeta_{p^{n+1}-1} \cdot p^n \qquad \qquad (II).$$

Now because $\zeta_{p^{j+1}-1} \notin R_i$ for all $j \ge i$, but $R_i \subset R$, the expressions $I$ and $II$ contradict the uniqueness of series representations with coefficients in $R$ in the field $\widehat{K^{ur}}$.

(It's also fun to see where exactly this kind of proof breaks down in my example in **1**. It happens not where one might first think: The series representations $\alpha = 17 p$ versus $\alpha = \sum \theta_i p^i$ do *not* contradict each other, because they do not share the same set of representatives as coefficients.)

Comment: “Of course…Lubin is aware of such things”, to which Lubin replies, “it ain’t necessarily so”. I know I have mistakes that are published, and am in no way infallible.

Comment: @Lubin: Very few people are infallible, but from the careful way you phrased things in your answer, I actually assumed you were aware of the fallacy in this supposed shortcut proof. In any case, I hope you don't find a flaw in what I wrote here ...