# Completeness of field may change under the extension of field, then what justifies $K^{nr}$ is complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory

Completeness of field does not change under the extension of field ?

Let $K$ be a valuation field and $v$ be one of it's valuation.
Let $K$ be complete with respect to $v$.

Then, arbitrary extension field of $K$ is also complete?

I heard this is not true in some case, but I couldn't find counterexamples.
If the titled question does not hold, then, the fact that $K^{nr}$($K's$ maximal unramified extension) is complete follows from
another reason?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximal unramified completion of $\mathbb Q_p$ is not complete. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/927760/127263) for a proof.

In fact, [an infinite separable extension of a complete field is never complete](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/cheltsov/gnt/hw4.pdf).

Comment: Thank you！What about finite　extension case？ Completeness holds？

Comment: Yes, see some references [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/223033/30186)